# show errors in vue component ( Noob question)

Tags: vue.js, error-handling

In a Vue component I am trying to store error status in a variable errorMessage

Somehow I do not get how to do it.

My method is:

```
         addSpeler(){
           
           const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name',this.name);
            formData.append('pass_code',this.pass_code);
            formData.append('game_id', this.currentGame.id);
            
            if(this.exists === false){
                //add
                fetch(`api/speler`, {
                    method: 'post',
                    body:formData,
                    headers:{
                        //'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                       // 'accept':'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(res => console.log(res))
                //.then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    this.name='';
                    this.code='';
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    this.errorMessage = err.res.status;
                    console.log(err);
                });

            } 
        },
```

The script works, I get a 201 error when the record is created.
I get a 500 error when the user cannot be created,

I cannot get the response.statusText and response.status stored in the  errorMessage

Clearly I do not understand some aprts of the concept.

can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You need to return a promise from the method and chain it in a place it's called. Currently this is obviously not done because a promise is not returned. *I cannot get the response.statusText and response.status stored in the errorMessage* - this isn't listed in the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to do the AJAX requests.

```
axios.post('url', formData)
.then( res => {/* success handler */})
.catch( err => { /* do your error handling here */})
```

for fetch function
you have everything in the first .then() block even if the request failed, then you have to return it to the second success handler which another .then() handler or throw it to the .catch() handler.

```
login (data, loginUrl) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(loginUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status !== 200) {
        return res.json().then(res => { throw res })
      }
      return res.json()
    })
    .then((res) => {
      this.setLoginSession(res)
      resolve(res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject(error)
    })
})}
```

hope that helps

Comment: Why would Axios be preferred?

Comment: it's abstracted and simple to use

Comment: How will this help solving the problem? fetch is abstracted and simple to use either when correctly used.

Comment: checkout this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/statusText

Comment: checkout my answer again

Comment: FWIW, this is promise constructor antipattern. fetch already returns a promise, there's no need to create a new one.

Comment: Thanks very much for your interest. I keep struggling with this.

Comment: Just learned that HTTP failures do not throw error and cannot be caught..

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: HTML errors 4xx and 5xx are not caught by .catch(),

```
  addSpeler(){
           
           const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name',this.name);
            formData.append('pass_code',this.pass_code);
            formData.append('game_id', this.currentGame.id);
            
            if(this.exists === false){
                //add
                fetch(`api/speler`, {
                    method: 'post',
                    body:formData,
                })
                .then(res => { 
                    if (!res.ok){
                        this.spelerAdded = false;
                        this.errorMessage = "something went wrong ... " + res.status + " " + res.statusText;
                    }
                    else{
                    res.json();
                    console.log(res);
                    this.spelerAdded = true;
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    this.errorMessage = err.res.status;
                    this.spelerAdded = false;
                    console.log(err);
                });

            } 
        },
```

this script did the trick for me.